# PostgreSQL COPY CSV with two NULL strings

Tags: postgresql, csv, null

I have a source of csv files from a web query which contains two variations of a string that I would like to class as NULL when copying to a PostgreSQL table.

e.g.

```
COPY my_table FROM STDIN WITH CSV DELIMITER AS ',' NULL AS ('N/A', 'Not applicable');
```

I know this query will throw an error so I'm looking for a way to specify two separate NULL strings in a COPY CSV query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your best bet in this case, since `COPY` does not support multiple `NULL` strings, is to set the `NULL` string argument to one of them, and then, once it's all loaded, do an `UPDATE` that will set values in any column you wish having the other `NULL` string you want to the actual `NULL` value (the exact query would depend on which columns could have those values).

If you have a bunch of columns, you could use `CASE` statements in your `SET` clause to return `NULL` if it matches your special string, or the value otherwise. `NULLIF` could also be used (that would be more compact). e.g. `NULLIF(col1, 'Not applicable')`

Comment: NULLIF could also be used (that would be more compact). e.g. NULLIF(col1, 'Not applicable') - that is a nice clean way. Many thanks.